# Why the second variable `PP` in the loop FOR nested not take the value PP=0

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, for-loop

```
y_vals,y_vals_max=[],[]

y_vals = [7,6,5,4,3,2,1,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

c = 0

for jj  in range(0,len (y_vals),1):
                   
            for pp in range(1, len(y_vals),1):
                if y_vals[jj] > y_vals[pp]:
                    if (y_vals[jj] - y_vals[pp]) >=0:
                        c = c + 1
                        y_vals_max.append(y_vals[jj]-y_vals[pp]) 
                        
                        print(y_vals[jj] - y_vals[pp])
                       # y_vals_max.append(t_vec[jj])
                        
                else:       
                    
                    print(y_vals_max)                
                    for jj in range(0,c+1,1):
                        y_vals.remove(y_vals[jj])
                    jj=0
                    pp=0
```

The Loop For above justed take the difference between from each element in the list y_vals = [7,6,5,4,3,2,1,7,6,5,4,3,2,1] until the logic reach if y_vals[jj] > y_vals[pp]. After that, the elements are removed from the list and start again, now with the second half elements. However, the variable PP start with PP= 8 and it not started with PP= 0 how it should.
Please, someone can help me what happened?

```
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJZZF.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJZZF.png)
```

```
The Loop For above justed take the difference between from each element in the list y_vals = [7,6,5,4,3,2,1,7,6,5,4,3,2,1] until the logic reach if y_vals[jj] > y_vals[pp]. After that, the elements are removed from the list and start again, now with the second half elements. However, the variable PP start with PP= 8 and it not started with PP= 0 how it should.
Please, someone can help me what happened?
```

I`ve expected que output were how follow below.

1
2
3
4
5
6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
1
2
3
4
5
6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: `pp` starts at `1` and your line `pp = 0` is effectively ignored.

Comment: The Question needs more details

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking at this i see the number "c" goes way above the number of length of y_vals. Each iteration that starts with 7-6, 7-5, 7-4.. up to 6-7 where first FOR breaks increases "c" by one. Then you remove elements from y_vals with index of range(c) which makes the whole y_vals list empty. Then it would set PP and JJ to 0 but it would search indexes of an empty list y_vals[0] and there you get "list index out of range" error. Please correct me if im wrong

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to clarify the first iteration ( Loop For nested) not makes the y_vals list empty. Because the iteration 7-6, 7-5... stop when it reaches  if y_vals[jj] > y_vals[pp] and run the ELSE instructions. So the list  it will reduce to y_vals = [7,6,5,4,3,2,1] and restart again. But the PP should get the value zero (PP=0), but it retain PP=8.

Comment: You are removing indexes with `y_vals.remove(y_vals[jj])`. If you put `y_vals.remove(jj)` then you gonna remove numbers. But you willl face different type of error `list.remove(x): x not in list`